# Why is the user agent stylesheet overriding my html{} style?

Tags: css

I have the following style on my html element:

```
html {
font-size: 16px;
font-family: "Harmonia Sans Regular" !important;
}
```

But even with `!important`, my font styling is still being overriden in things like inputs. 
[image]

Why? I thought inherited styles trumped user agent styling?

Comment: TL:DR: inheritance is the last resort, only used when no style are defined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. If you want your styles to have precedence, they need to apply to the same element. Which, in our case, is `input`.

You have applied styles to the `html` element, not to `input`.
Now, if you changed your selector to `html *`, to `html input`, to `input` or to `*`, it would be a different story... The two selectors *would* get compared and yours *would* have precedence.

The only difference between your selectors and the ones in the default browser stylesheet is yours are loading later, hence, provided you have the same specificity, yours apply. So the minimum selector for yours to apply would be `input {}`.

But the important bit here is: `html {}` only styles inheritable `input` properties which are **not defined** (not set) at element level. If they are set inheritance does not happen (there's no need to inherit, because the property resolves). The `input` set value applies, regardless of values and specificity on any of the parents. In fact, if what you're expecting would happen, designing web would be **a lot** more difficult and a lot less flexible (IMHO).

---

Which is a reaaaaaly long way of saying: change

```
html {/* globals here*/}
```

into:

```
* {/* globals here */}
```

... and they'll probably work as intended. But be warned: it **will** apply to all elements, and you **will** soon understand why the way inheritance works is, in fact, quite smart (and helpful).